# Using GetHostEntry in CF3.5 on WinCE 6.0 device

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I have a WinCE 6.0 device with CF3.5 installed.

I have 2 DNS-serverip entered in my lan-configuration:

10.12.21.1 (sometimes unreachable)
10.12.21.2 (reachable)

When I call GetHostEntry("10.12.21.5") then I get the IPAddress from the first DNS server (10.12.21.1) not the ip from "someip". This just happens when the first DNS Server is not reachable in the moment of the call.
And this only happens in CF3.5. With CF2.0 it works as it should.

Why GetHostEntry doesn't try to query the second DNS Server to give me the right ip back: "10.12.21.5"?

Do anyone make the same expiriences with CF3.5?